# Can my Kindle paper white read a flash drive

Tags: kindle-paperwhite

If I had a 30GB flash drive, can I load it with ebooks and then stick it to my kindle paper white? Will the kindle be able to read the books?

Comment: I am not familiar with the various kindle models, but couldn't you just buy a 32G micro-SD card  and stick it in? That is what I use with my (non-kindle) reader and for bulk transfers I get it out because I have a USB3 SD card readers that is much faster than the USB2 ebook reader connection.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the only external storage you can use is Amazon's cloud storage.

Comment: Can you please explain why there is a down vote? Is this answer wrong?